# Prove for every positive integer $n$, one of $n, n+1, n+2,...,2n$ is the square of an integer

Tags: number-theory

Prove for every positive integer $n$, one of $n, n+1, n+2,...,2n$ is the square of an integer.

This seems like a proof by induction, but I'm more used to using proof by induction with a single equation, where I usually prove it's true for the base case then assume it's true for n and prove n+1 this is true, but I don't think that applies here.

Comment: 1 is the square of an integer--1^2 = 1

Comment: However, $n=5$ seems to be a counterexample: $5, 6, 7, 10$ are all non-square.

Comment: sorry there should have been dots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $x^2<n$ but $(x+1)^2\ge n$.

Then, if $x\ge3, 2x+1<x^2,$ so $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1<2x^2<2n.$

The cases where $x\lt3$ can be easily eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

The cases from $n=1$ to $n=6$ are clear. As for $n\geq 6$, since

$$\sqrt{2n}-\sqrt{n}=(\sqrt{2}-1)\sqrt{n}\geq(\sqrt{2}-1)\sqrt{6}>1,$$

there will always be an integer $k$ between them for which $n\leq k^2\leq 2n$.

P.S. This terminology does not look very satisfying, but I hope it would help after all.

Answer (score 0):

Let S(n) be the statement "There exists a square in $\{n,n+1,...,2n\}$."

We have $S(1).$

We show $S(n)\implies S(n+1):$

(i). If there is a square in $\{n+1,...,2n\}$ then that square is in $\{(n+1),...,2(n+1)\},$ & we're done.

(ii). If  $n$ is a square,  let $n=x^2$ with $x\in \Bbb N.$ Now (obviously) $ (x+1)^2\ge x^2+1=n+1.$ So we have $S(n+1)$ IF we have $(x+1)^2\le 2(n+1).$ We have $$(x+1)^2\le 2(n+1)\iff$$ $$ \iff (x+1)^2\le 2(x^2+1)\iff$$ $$ \iff x^2+2x+1\le 2x^2+2\iff $$ $$\iff 0\le x^2-2x+1=(x-1)^2.$$